43mm Solvent Weld -> 41mm Compression Coupler
From the UK here.
I have some existing solvent weld waste pipe (43mm).
I would like to connect this to some compression/push fit style pipes (at 41mm).
Could someone tell me if this coupler would do the job, please? It looks like it does, but the product description provides a confusing summary.
All help would be appreciated.
Thanks
